# How do I capture inputs from a system.out.println to compare if they match?

Tags: java, methods, boolean

I am a first year studying app development and I have a login and registration assignment.
But Im struggling to make a method where it checks if the username and password registered matches the entered login details?
I am mostly using `System.out.println`

Here is the Login.java

```
package st10035771;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {
    public final static int USERNAME_LIMIT = 5;
    public final static int PASSWORD_LENGTH = 8;
    private static String userName;
    private static String userPass;
    private static String message;
    private static String firstName;
    private static String lastName;
    public static Scanner un = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static boolean checkUserName(String userName) {
        if (userName.length() <= USERNAME_LIMIT && userName.contains("_")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    /*
     * code attribute
     * this code was adapted from DelftStack
     * https://www.delftstack.com/howto/java/password-checker-java/
     */
    public static boolean checkPasswordComplexity(String userPass) {
        boolean isValidPassword = false;
        final int minUppers = 1;
        final int minDigits = 1;
        final int minSpecials = 1;
        int uppers = 0;
        int digits = 0;
        int specials = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < userPass.length(); i++) {
            char ch = userPass.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(ch))
                uppers++;
            else if (Character.isDigit(ch))
                digits++;
            // if (ch >= 33 && ch <= 47 || ch == 64) {
            if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(ch)) {
                specials++;
            }

        }

        if (userPass.length() >= PASSWORD_LENGTH && uppers >= minUppers && digits >= minDigits
                && specials >= minSpecials) {

            return isValidPassword = true;
        }
        return isValidPassword;
    }

    public static void inputUser() {
        System.out.println("Please enter username:");

        setUserName(un.next());

        if (checkUserName(userName)) {
            System.out.println("Username successfully captured");
        } else {
            System.out.println(
                    "Username is not correctly formatted, please ensure that your username contains an underscore and is no more than 5 characters in length.");
        }
    }

    public static void inputFName() {
        System.out.println("Please enter your name:");
        setFirstName(un.next());
        System.out.println("Please enter your surname:");
        setLastName(un.next());
    }

    public static void inputPass() {
        System.out.println("Please enter password:");
        setUserPass(un.next());

        if (checkPasswordComplexity(userPass)) {
            System.out.println("Password successfully captured");
        } else {
            System.out.println(
                    "Password is not correctly formatted, please ensure that the password contains at least 8 characters, a capital letter, a number and a special character.");
        }
    }

    public static String registerUser() {

if((checkUserName(userName)) == false){
        return "Username is not correctly formatted, please ensure that your username contains an underscore and is no more than 5 characters in length.";
    }
if((checkPasswordComplexity(userPass)) == false){
        return "Password is not correctly formatted, please ensure that the password contains at least 8 characters, a capital letter, a number and a special character";
    }

return "Welcome " +firstName+" "+lastName+",it is great to see you.";
        

    }
    
    public boolean loginUser(){
        if ((registerUser())  ==  )
        
    }

    /**
     * @param aUserPass the userPass to set
     */
    public static void setUserPass(String aUserPass) {
        userPass = aUserPass;
    }

    /**
     * @param aMessage the message to set
     */
    public static void setMessage(String aMessage) {
        message = aMessage;
    }

    /**
     * @param aFirstName the firstName to set
     */
    public static void setFirstName(String aFirstName) {
        firstName = aFirstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param aLastName the lastName to set
     */
    public static void setLastName(String aLastName) {
        lastName = aLastName;
    }

    /**
     * @param aUserName the userName to set
     */
    public static void setUserName(String aUserName) {
        userName = aUserName;
    }
}
```

The method in question is `loginUser()`

Comment: Instead of capturing output from `System.out`, why not make a method that returns the result as some object (maybe even string, or an enumeration instance) that you can then compare things to?

Comment: I know what you mean but I don't think I can use anything other than System.out because the lecturer wants us to use it..

Comment: You can use whatever the method returns (say, an enumeration object) to still determine what to call `System.out` with. Or instead ask your lecturer on how to capture `out` and why does he want to do that. Generally speaking, the program never captures its own `out` - no one does that. You could capture another program's `out`, but I doubt it's your current task.

Comment: `if((checkUserName(userName)) == false)` don't compare boolean function results with booleans, use the `not` operator of the language

Comment: I think we hardly use system Out to capture input. And your error code is not complete.

Answer (score 0):

You have username and password as `userName` and `userPass` data members, respectively, so you will need to pass the textual data you have received from a form and compare it with your data members:

```
public boolean loginUser(username, password){
    if (this.userName.equals(username) && this.userPass.equals(password)) {
        //Perform the login
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When you call this method, based on the result (`true` or `false` you can decide what to print out). Notice that I have a comment which says "perform the login". Since it is unclear how you intend to log in I did not implement it. Note that you have a `Login` `class`, which seems to be more like an action and you need a `User` class. Also, making everything `static` is an antipattern. So, there are lots of things to improve in your code, but I'm only focusing on the aspect you have been asking the question about.

Also, `System.out.println` is a way to display your `output` to the console, you do not need to load anything back from the console. The teacher probably told you that you can output the results using `System.out.println`, not to read from it.